# SSH is not working on Mac OS

Tags: macos, ssh

Whenever I try to ssh some place, that happens:

```
$ ssh user@someip
MK-AUTH/Debian Linux V4
user@someip's password:
```

I type the correct password and it does not work. I guess the problem is related with "MK-AUTH/Debian Linux V4". It has not appeared before.

Comment: Have you tried ssh'ing somewhere else?

Comment: You are trying to ssh by IP, instead of by name?  Perhaps the machine you are connecting to isn't the machine you want.  Did you get a server key change warning?